# Ajax success function with data-id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a feed page that loads an individual `feedLikes.php` for each post on the feed. Currently, I can like each post and it updates the likes using Ajax. However, every time a like is updated, it returns to the top of the feed. Below is `feedLikes.php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['feedID'])) {
    $feedID = ($_POST['feedID']);
    $findHasUserLiked = $pdo->prepare('SELECT username FROM feedLikes WHERE feedID =? and username=?');
    //execute query and variables
    $findHasUserLiked->execute([$feedID, $username]);
    if ($findHasUserLiked->rowCount() > 0) {
        $hasUserLiked = $findHasUserLiked->fetchColumn();
        echo <<<_END
        <form action="feedLikes.php" id="unlikePostForm$feedID" method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="unLikeButton"></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="feedIDForUnlike" class="feedIDForUnlike$feedID" value="$feedID">
        </form>
_END;

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#likePostForm<?php echo $feedID ?>').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var feedIDLike = $(".feedIDForLike<?php echo $feedID ?>").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "feedLikesClicked.php",
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        feedIDLike: feedIDLike
                    },
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (html) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
<?php
} else {
        echo <<<_END
        <form action="feedLikes.php" id="likePostForm$feedID" method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="likeButton"></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="feedIDForLike" class="feedIDForLike$feedID" value="$feedID">
        </form>
_END;
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#likePostForm<?php echo $feedID ?>').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var feedIDLike = $(".feedIDForLike<?php echo $feedID ?>").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "feedLikesClicked.php",
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        feedIDLike: feedIDLike
                    },
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (html) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
<?php
}
    $likesNumber = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM feedLikes WHERE feedID =?');
    //execute query and variables
    $likesNumber->execute([$feedID]);
    $numberOfLikes = $likesNumber->fetchColumn();
    print '<div class=numberOfLikes data-id="' . $feedID . '">
            <p>' . $numberOfLikes . '</p>
        </div>';
}
```

I'm aware this is because `location.reload()` is actually reloading all the `feedLikes.php` pages, not just the one post i have liked. However, i can't seem to figure out what success function i need to use to just update the one post and not take me back to the top of the feed.

I have tried placing everything in `feedLikes.php` in a div like so:

```
<div class=allLikesPage data-id="'.$feedID .'">
```

and then in the ajax success using this line:

```
$('.allLikesPage[data-id='"+ feedID +"']').load(document.URL +  ' .allLikesPage[data-id='"+ feedID +"']');
```

However that just removes everything and doesn't update. I've also tried the same thing without the data-id amongst other things.

Comment: you need to calculate likes after liking and then override the likes show on the feed manually if you donot want to reload and update only that feed, you should use json response from the php file , means create an array put total like on one index and then put success true or false on another and then use json_encode on that array and wcho it, then in your readystate function use $.parseJson to parsedata and use it like data.success, data.likes

Comment: wow. I really appreciate all that and thankyou but is there any chance you could write this as an answer with some code. I'm very new to it all and not suure how to go about using $.parseJson etc.

Comment: ok just give some time , i will when i get back to my seat

Comment: Hi @MuhammadOmerAslam, sorry to bother you. I've given a few things a go to no avail :/

Comment: yeah i would be posting for you in a while. working on an example

Comment: just posted an answer for you , if you get into troubles do post here the error you are receiving, we can sort it out, take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go you can see the example [here](http://omaraslam.com/example.php) I had to show how the `ajax` response should be encoded so I added the example on my domain

your `PHP` file will look like the following, I have omitted the `SQL` part and added only the logic on how to use `json_encode` with the arrays hope you find it helpful you can use this code on your local machine to look into how things are working

```
<?php 
$response   =   array('success'=>false,'likes'=>0);


if(isset($_POST['count'])){
    $counter =   $_POST['count'];
    $response['likes']=$counter+1;
    $response['success']=true;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

your HTML page is below

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        .feed {
            width: 95%;
            height: auto;
        }

        i.fa {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".voteup").click(function () {
                var curElement = $(this);
console.log(curElement.parent().find('.likes').text());
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'test.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: 'count=' + curElement.parent().find(".likes").text(),
                    method: 'POST'
                }).done(function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        curElement.parent().find(".likes").html(data.likes);
                    } else {
                        alert('Some Error occoured at the server while liking the feed');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="feed">
                <p>This is my feed can someone like it</p>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up voteup" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="likes">0</span>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down votedown" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="dlikes">0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="feed">
                <p>Another feed item</p>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up voteup" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="likes">0</span>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down votedown" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="dlikes">0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="feed">
                <p>This is my feed can someone like it</p>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up voteup" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="likes">0</span>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down votedown" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="dlikes">0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="feed">
                <p>This is my feed can someone like it</p>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up voteup" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="likes">0</span>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down votedown" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="dlikes">0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="feed">
                <p>This is my feed can someone like it</p>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up voteup" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="likes">0</span>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down votedown" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="dlikes">0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="feed">
                <p>This is my feed can someone like it</p>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up voteup" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="likes">0</span>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down votedown" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <span class="dlikes">0</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>


</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Basically, I am just incrementing the posted variable `count` you do not have to do that you just need to update likes in the database once you send the ajax call and then count with an `SQL` query and show the output in the same format I have used.And about the `$.parseJSON()` you will notice that the ajax call used here has the `dataType` set to `JSON` if you have set the `dataType` you do not need to parse the response otherwise you should use `var myData=$.parseJSON(data);` and then use like `myData.likes` `myData.success`